# Где моя проблема? Чтение из файла и сортировка пузырьком

Tags: python

```
def check(l):
    a = 0
    while True:
        b = a + 1
        if b == len(l):
            break
        if l[a] > l[b]:
            a -= 1
            break
        a += 1
    return a + 1


def bubble(l,a):
    i = a - 1
    l.insert(i,l.pop(a))
    return l


l = []
f = open('C:\\Users\\davla\\Desktop\\teachers.txt','r')
nums=f.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(nums)):
    l.append(list(nums[i].split('_')))


while True:
    n=input('sort by ')
    if n == 'exp' or n == 'expirience':
        k = 2
        break
    elif n=='school':
        k = 1
        break
    else:
        print('you entered wrong key')

while True:
    m = [int(l[i][k]) for i in range(len(l))]
    print(m)
    a = check(m)
    print(a)
    l = bubble(l,a)
    print(l)
    if a-1==len(m):
        break


f.close()
```

```
TXT
Ivan_260_8_math
Andrew_30_7_eng
Alex_125_10_his
```

Comment: Вы упомянули файл. Можете, пожалуйста, привести его в вопрос? Хотя бы частично.

Comment: @nomnoms12 txt файл

Comment: @HoupS, используйте \`\`\`, а не ''', чтобы текст тут как код представить :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то все очень сложно.

```
print (l)
while True:
    n=input('sort by ')
    if n == 'exp' or n == 'expirience':
        k = 2
        break
    elif n=='school':
        k = 1
        break
    else:
        print('you entered wrong key')
n=1
while n < len(l):
     for i in range(len(l)-n):
         if int(l[i][k]) > int(l[i+1][k]):
             l[i],l[i+1] = l[i+1],l[i]
     n += 1
print (l)
```

Имеем:

```
[['Ivan', '260', '8', 'math'], ['Andrew', '30', '7', 'eng'], ['Alex', '125', '10','his']]
sort by school
[['Andrew', '30', '7', 'eng'], ['Alex', '125', '10', 'his'], ['Ivan', '260', '8','math']]
```

и

```
[['Ivan', '260', '8', 'math'], ['Andrew', '30', '7', 'eng'], ['Alex', '125', '10', 'his']]
sort by expirience
[['Andrew', '30', '7', 'eng'], ['Ivan', '260', '8', 'math'], ['Alex', '125', '10', 'his']]
```